# Starting a thread on pushbutton

Tags: c++, multithreading

How would I make sure to create only a single thread on pushbutton without being accidently double-clicked?

Comment: This is known as "debouncing". See e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/15/242761.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do it (Under win32) ...

```
EnterCriticalSection( &critSec );
if ( ghThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    ghThread    = ::CreateThread( NULL, stackSize, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadEntry, NULL, 0, NULL );
}
LeaveCriticalSection( &critSec );
```

This does of course assume you initialise the ghThread HANDLE to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE in advance.

Comment: That depends. Can more than one thread accesses this function?

Comment: @Martin: you are right martin ... sticking a critical section round the entire block would solve the issue ... edited

Comment: @Goz: shouldn't be needed, it's win32. The pushbutton has thread affinity, which means that all clicks arrive on the same thread. Since this bit of code is not reentrant (`ThreadEntry` cannot retrieve pushbutton messages) it means that the pushbutton messages are handled in order.

Comment: @MSalters:  Thats a very good point ... no harm, other than small speed hit, in it though :)

Comment: @Goz: technically, yes. However, it's a problem for people who'll read the code later. It suggests that the code can be called from multiple threads, yet it will appear in other (GUI) code that will assume thread affinity. That's a red flag, such combinations are usually bugs.

Comment: @MSalters:  I was going to edit the critical section out but it occurs to me that it is possible for the function to be called directly from another thread.  It ought not to be done but I've seen it done loads of times before ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about windows programming? 
I'm not too familiar with that, but you should catch [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607%28VS.85%29.aspx) message (or Double click) and set some bool flag to TRUE. And all you need is not to create thread if this flag is TRUE. It must be initialized as FALSE of cource.

Comment: What's the point of the flag? Also, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` doesn't have a double click indication. It's not even a single click, only the first half of it. You need separate up/down messages for drag-n-drop, not for clicks.